# Finite versus infinite on non-Hausdorff topologies

Tags: gn.general-topology, mathematical-philosophy, mp.mathematical-physics

**Question:** Does there exist some real-valued function $f(x)$ where $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, for which $\lim_{x \to \infty}$ converges on a *non*-Hausdorff topology but does *not* converge on a Hausdorff topology?

For the purposes of this post, let me first define what I take to be a Hausdorff topology:

**Definition:**  A topology, T$_{2}$, is Hausdorff if and only if for any two points $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$, where $x_{1} \ne x_{2}$, there exist open sets, $O_{1}$ and $O_{2}$ such that $x_{1} \in O_{1}$; $x_{2} \in O_{2}$; and $O_{1} \cap O_{2} = \oslash$ where $\oslash$ is the null set.

**Example of a *non*-Hausdorff topology:**  Define a set $\varepsilon_{4}$ consisting of all the events of ordinary (3+1)-dimensional Minkowski space, $M^{4}$.  Remove the set $F$ containing the spacetime event 0, and all subsequent events both inside and on the future light-cone with its vertex at 0.  Replace $F$ by two copies, $F_{1}$ and $F_{2}$.  The basis for such a topology on $\varepsilon_{4}$ is thus (1) any open set in [$M^{4}-F$]$\cup F_{1}$ is an open set in $\varepsilon_{4}$; (2) and open set in [$M^{4}-F$]$\cup F_{2}$ is an open set in $\varepsilon_{4}$.

Comment: As far as I can see, your question does mot make much sense. Can yo elaborate on what you mean by 'finite', for example?

Comment: Edited for clarity.

Comment: You still have not said what you mean by finite.  As it stands, this question should be closed for revision.  

Comment: Um, how much clearer could I be?  And I quote, "By finite I mean that it has a finite structure, i.e. a finite cardinality for a set or a finite sequence or series."

Comment: @Ian, the cardinality of a set exists outside of a topology on it.  Could you give some examples of "finite" objects?  Can you give some examples as to what you mean?

Comment: Look, I have a meeting I have to go to.  But if what I said means nothing, then you need to haul me out of the classroom because "finite cardinality" and "finite sequence" are definitions I teach to students in Modern Algebra and Real Analysis respectively which means I've been teaching meaningless things for ten years.

Comment: All of the objects that you listed are "structures on sets". Obviously, fixing any one of those, then changing the topology is not going to change the cardinality of anything regarding the algebraic structure, except maybe something worthless like "the number of open subgroups", which I can't see having any importance unless the group is a topological group.

Comment: @Tom:  Thank you for clarifying in a more helpful way what everyone is asking.  I thought my above example was pretty clear - trying to relate the mathematical extension of Birkfhoff's theorem to the quantum world to the physical realization thereof.

Comment: @Harry:  Look, it seems pretty clear from my example and my motivation what I'm attempting to do.  I'm attempting to reconcile certain mathematical results with physical reality, vis-a-vis the Quine-Putnam argument.  How I do that makes no difference to me.  But I think it's a valid question and I thought it was pretty clear.

Comment: It is the phrase "when considered in the context of ..." that makes us unsure what is meant by "finite" here.

Comment: I have read your question again and again and still cannot understand what you mean. Let's take one of your example: sequences. Then your question reads: "does there exist a sequence that is known to be finite when considered in the context of a Hausdorff topology but infinite in the context of a non-Hausdorff topology?". Now, you just have a sequence, I don't know of what. What topology are you talking about?

Comment: @Ian, here's another point of clarification.  Let X be a set.  Then a sequence is an enumerated collection of points of X.  Notice that there's no topology here, it's just a set of points {x_i}.  It's either finite or infinite; there are no topological considerations on its size. Topology only enters the picture when you talk about convergence.  That is, under some topologies on X, the sequence {x_i} converges; under others, it doesn't.  (Of course, under some topologies, this is a meaningless question)

Comment: I agree with the other commenters that the question is ill-posed; however, I've made some amateurish attempts below to answer/discuss what *might* have been the intended meta-question.

Comment: @Ian: it's not going to benefit anyone if you get defensive.  No one is saying that you are not a competent mathematician.  Rather they are saying that you simply haven't yet succeeded in communicating the meaning of your question to us.  It sounds like you are saying that you want to change the cardinality of a set by changing the topology that is placed on it.  This is certainly not possible, so it can't be what you really mean to ask.  What is it that you really mean to ask, in mathematical terms?  (You *are* asking a math question, and not a physics or philosophy question?) 

Comment: @Pete:  My apologies if I sounded defensive.  Very, very long week of administrative "to-dos."  On the other hand, responses like Tom's are far more helpful than simply saying "this question makes no sense."

@Reid: Originally I had said "on" rather than "when considered in the context of" but I thought that was part of what confused people.  I'm not a topologist so I wasn't sure how to word it.

@Tom:  That is **exactly** what I'm getting at.  So, for example, does a sequence exist that happens to converge for non-Hausdorff topologies while *not* converging for Hausdorff topologies?

Comment: Ian, that's completely different from the question you asked.

Comment: Sorry, I'm voting to close.  Incidentally, the alternating sequence on a 2 point set converges in the trivial topology but not the discrete (Hausdorff) topology.

Comment: My instinct is to get defensive again considering the last two comments.  @QY: I fail to see how it's different than what I originally asked.  I was looking for a mathematical structure or object that behaved differently depending on/under a Hausdorff v. a non-Hausdorff topology, specifically in relation to the finiteness of that structure.  @SC: Fine, close it.  My week-long experiment with this site is officially done.

Comment: (Ian, I'm also responding to your post on Yemon's answer)
I'm very skeptical of making these kinds of connections. I don't doubt that mathematical physicists do plenty of important, interesting, and experimentally-justified work, but I think talking about a topology on the "multiverse" is meaningless speculation, even if it is just an analogy. Also, just to reiterate the point others have made: being Hausdorff or non-Hausdorff has nothing to do with cardinality. 

Comment: There is no reason why a (supposed) topology on the so-called "multiverse" would imply anything about how many "universes" there are, and so would not help your attempt to realize an infinity in the real world.

Although, I am a Hilbert formalist (i.e., "math is a fancy pencil and paper game"), so maybe that is why I don't understand your point of view. 

Comment: @Zev: the connection between non-Hausdorff topologies and the notion of a multiverse is a simple extension of an idea put forward by Visser about 15 years ago.  I find it ironic that some mathematicians (note: I have a PhD in math, not physics) who work on tremendously abstract problems, many of which have no relation to the real, physical world, find things like this "speculative."  Regarding the cardinality thing, I thought perhaps it might have some relation in terms of topological groups.  But, in any case, it was simply an example.

Comment: The supposed ironic contrast between "abstract problems ... no relation to the real, physical world" and "finding things like this speculative" seems wide of the mark. Abstraction does not equate to vagueness, surely?

Comment: I agree, Yemon, I don't see how it's ironic - pure mathematicians are not attempting to make claims about the real world, and hence are not actually speculating. Algebraic geometry, category theory, etc. are certainly abstract, as is talk of a "multiverse"; but the math is completely invented. The claim that such a thing as a "multiverse" exists, as a part of the real, material world, needs to have the experimental scrutiny any other scientific claim does.

Comment: Then "speculative" is not the correct term.  The multiverse is not a speculation.  It is an interpretation.  There is a difference.  Quantum mechanics suffers from the lack of a single, consistent conceptual interpretation.  In other words, we've got experimental results and a lot of math that matches those results, but no one can agree on the conceptual link between the two.  Many-worlds (and thus the multiverse) is considered an interpretation of existing experimental results based on certain logical assumptions (and I will repeat that I am agnostic on this issue).

Comment: (A)  Why I voted +1:  (i) I vote up any question that is well-formatted, with citations, etc.  (ii) I think there's a well-formed mathematics question in there somewhere.  (iii) I don't think this question should be at -3, compared to other questions on this site.  (B) However, it's clear that the question as written must be revised.  For example, the first "example" is trivial as S.C. mentioned above.  I think that I.D. wants to restrict the topologies on his set via some unexplained physical considerations.

Comment: Oh, and Zev, whether any math is invented or not is a hotly debated topic in foundational circles and even beyond (since it is finding relevance in fields as far-ranging as biology).

Comment: Thank you Theo.  I will make another concerted effort to revise this before completely abandoning ship.  However, it is now well past my bed time and it will have to wait until the weekend.

Comment: @Theo, I think the author's question was in fact what it appeared to be (can you put different topologies on a set to make the set become finite or infinite?). Obviously this is not a good question. I think the reason people gave him the benefit of the doubt and asked for clarification was so as not to be insulting (and maybe also because all the extra Quine-Putnam stuff and so on confused the issue). 

Comment: If anyone else thinks they are starting to get what I'm trying to say (it seemed like Theo and Tom and maybe Yemon might be close), feel free to edit away whilst I am otherwise occupied with sleep, classes, and meetings.

Comment: @Mike: No, that wasn't what I was asking.  I had no specific mathematical structure or object in mind, i.e. obviously the wording I used relating to sets was poor and confusing.  But I could care less if it is a set or a sequence or whatever.  I just want to be able to model what I explained in the motivation part.  I actually think Theo is getting close.

Comment: @Ian: Topologies are on sets. You want to put a topology on your object, so it must be a set. Any additional structure (whether it's a group or whatever else) is not relevant.

Comment: @Mike: But that set could be some kind of sequence, as Tom pointed out above.

Comment: @Ian: How is that relevant? 

Comment: @Mike: I'm not sure I understand your question.  Personally, Tom's example seems precisely relevant.  In fact it seems like it could fit my physical example quite well.  Look, this is all ultimately motivated by the fact that, while mathematicians often like to live in highly abstract worlds (re-note: my PhD is in math, not physics), it is a fact that math is used every single day to accomplish a host of tasks.  But it is impossible to correlate certain types of mathematical results to physical situations.  So, somewhere, math and the physical world diverge.  I want to know where that happens.

Comment: @Ian: I'm aware that it's debated. But here's what I don't understand - are you *primarily* asking for a mathematical model of the scenario in your second example box (in which case the rest of the text of your question - Hausdorff topologies, mathematical philosophy, etc. - is somewhat superfluous)? Or are you *primarily* looking for an example of mathematical objects of infinite cardinality being essential to a physical theory, in which case I'm sure there are much simpler examples? 

Comment: Each question, asked separately and without extraneous material, I think is certainly appropriate for MO, but the conflation between them is I think what makes your question confusing.

Comment: Ian, it has been over thirty comments and you still have not told us what you think "finite" means.  What does the convergence of a sequence have to do with its cardinality?  (I am staying out of the rest of this conversation; I just really, really want to know what you're talking about.)

Comment: @Qiaochu: he means "finite" :) To be fair that isn't the part which is confusing. It's the use of "object" which I think may be causing some of the mutual confusion.

Comment: @Yemon, it seems to me he actually means something like "finitely describable," but I can't say for sure.  Again I would really appreciate some clarification and I hope Ian does not think I'm trying to criticize anything or anyone.  

@Ian, it also seems that your definition of Hausdorff is wrong (every topology satisfies the condition you wrote down), and T2 is the name of the condition, not the space.

Comment: @Qiaochu: He did say '"finite cardinality" and "finite sequence" are definitions I teach to students'. I think he does mean just finite. 

Comment: Then are we in agreement that the cardinality of a set does not change depending on what topology is placed on it?  Is this statement of pure mathematics insulting to anyone?  I am very confused.

Comment: I have closed the question.  This is not intended as a judgment that it was intrinsically valueless, but rather that it simply wasn't clear as a mathematical question, and the sequence of comments was not making substantial progress towards clarification.  I invite you to try again.  Suggestions: 1) stick entirely to mathematics.  2) make sure you use terminology in a standard way.  3) proofread your question [the current version defines a Hausdorff space -- which seems unnecessary, BTW -- but the definition given is incorrect]).

Comment: Ian, the (philosophical) question you pose in your blog post (http://quantummoxie.wordpress.com/2010/01/31/the-nature-of-mathematics/) is interesting and I think if you were to post that as a separate (soft, community wiki) question people would be happy to answer.

Comment: I absolutely agree with Qiaochu - it's a good community wiki kind of question, and it'd be interesting to get a sense of where most mathematicians stand on the issue of discovered vs. invented. However, I would hope that the "many worlds" idea doesn't muddy the waters again.

Comment: Regarding my definition of a Hausdorff topology, it is verbatim from a book by Visser (albeit not a book on topology).  If it is incorrect, though, it highlights something that this thread also highlights - pure mathematicians and many of those who apply mathematics in their work, have a serious disconnect.  Visser is a well-regarded mathematical physicist.  Again, I'm not saying he's right, but it highlights the fact that we're not all speaking the same language here.

Comment: @Zev: Let me add that nowhere on this site does it say that it is restricted to "pure" (vs. applied) mathematics questions.  In the context of the problem I am addressing, the multiverse was the motivation for my question.

Comment: @Ian: There must be a typo in that book if that is verbatim, because not only is that not the definition of Hausdorff, but it's an entirely useless definition! Hausdorff replaces to $\ne$ with $=$.  The definition yuo give is satisfied by every topological space: take the open set ot be the whole space.  So this can't just be an example of disconnect, if people are seriously working with that definition, they're just doing point-set topology with no Hausdorff condition.

Comment: @Ian: The only explanation then is that it's a typo (if your last "$\neq$" were a "=", it'd be correct) - not some kind of linguistic disconnect. 

Yes, MathOverflow is open to applied math questions, and we're trying very hard lately to give a fair shot to them. However, I think that your best bet would be to ask, say, about a specific calculation or equation in quantum mechanics - how it's interpreted in terms of cosmology is strictly outside mathematics and arguably has no right answer.

Comment: @Ian: the definition of Hausdorff space you had on your whiteboard a couple years ago is the correct one. This one is different from that one. 

Comment: @Mike: Ok, that's creepy.  Who are you and how do you know what was on my whiteboard several years ago?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I clicked your name and a few clicks later I was here: 
http://qwiki.stanford.edu/wiki/Ian_Durham

It was too much of a weird/funny coincidence not to mention it. 

Comment: I would have been more impressed if you'd said something like "I know who you are and I know where you live" and then laughed in an evil manner.

At any rate, if that is indeed correct, then I must have put in a typo here.  I'm too tired to look at the moment.

Comment: @ID: Your new edit is much clearer.  Only two issues now: (i) limit as x approaches infinity of a real-valued function doesn't make sense without some fixed topology on R in mind, since infinity is not a point of R.  (ii) You are missing quantifiers: SOME Hausdorff topology?  ALL Hausdorff topologies? etc.

Comment: Let f be your favorite real-valued function whose limit as x approaches 0 does not exist.  Thus the standard Euclidean topology on R is a Hausdorff topology on which the limit does not exist.  Conversely, consider the trivial, or indiscrete topology on R [or any set]: the only open sets are the empty set and the set itself.  Then (standard exercise) every function from a topological space to an indiscrete topological space is continuous.  So equipping R with the indiscrete topology, the limit of f as x approaches 0 will exist (but not be unique!).

Comment: Note: If f: X -> Y is a map between topological spaces, then by "lim_{x -> c} f(x) = L", I mean: if we redefine the value of f at c to be equal to L, then f will be continuous at c.  

Comment: @Pete - He didn't actually say that f was real valued; I read the question as assuming the standard topology on R and that f:R->X for some topological space X. Assuming that is what you meant, Ian, then Scott's answer earlier in the comment thread suffices: the "alternating sequence on a 2 point set converges in the trivial topology but not the discrete (Hausdorff) topology." For example, by setting f(x)=a\in {a,b} for x\in[2n,2n+1) and f(x)=b\in {a,b} for x\in[2n+1,2n+2), as x->infinity the function f would alternate between the two elements.

Comment: @Zev: Hmm, I guess there is still some ambiguity in the question (much less, though).  ID said "Hausdorff topology", not "Hausdorff topological space", so I assumed that he wanted to put a new topology on R.  Anyway, the answers are easy and similar either way: for instance, the example you give works for my interpretation as well (i.e., take X = R and retopologize both the domain and codomain).

Comment: A space is Hausdorff if and only if any two distinct points can be "housed off" in disjoint open sets.  

Comment: BTW, here is another way of construing the question: given any function f: R -> R, does there exist a Hausdorff topology on R (the same topology on the domain and codomain) such that f is continuous at 0?  Such that f is continuous everywhere?  

Comment: Yeah, I've also got a space that's not Hausdorff for you: consider the Real line with the indiscrete topology =\.

Comment: Hmmm.  OK, now we're getting somewhere.  I have to go haul some wood, but I'll ponder these suggestions as I do and try to make additional changes.

Comment: Pete is correct that I specifically want the output to be real-valued.  I assumed f: R -> R for simplicity, though now that I think about it I would also be interested to know this for any f: C -> R.

Answer (score 3):

Seeing as the comment thread to the original question is running out of control, let me just record some attempts to formulate a question which might (a) be related to what Ian Durham is asking, and (b) is more palatable to some of the people, myself included, who find the original question hard to answer meaningfully.

First of all: I guess we are taking as a working principle

> ... it is impossible to simultaneously have an infinite number of physical objects of non-zero size in the universe

The example given of an object in the original question is something like "a quantum channel" - now since I'm a physics ignoramus I don't know what the ontological status is of such a beast, but let's suppose for sake of discussion that it does have "size" and that therefore only finitely many of such can exist in a given physical system. This is presumably some argument about physical observables being quantized, but someone else is welcome to correct me on this.

Secondly: there are constructions in mathematical physics which seem to be of an infinite nature. The example given seems to be a "potential infinity", i.e. what are we approaching if we tensor a channel with itself repeatedly.

Now, my interpretation of what Ian may be trying to ask -- and I have to say, in my personal opinion I've not found it at all easy to discern what his underlying question *is* -- goes like this:

(i) are there contexts in "mainstream abstract mathematics" where an implicitly defined "object" -- such as, the solution space of some differential equation, the solution set of some algebraic equation, the set of accumulation points of some sequence -- which *depends* on some outside *flavour* (choice of ground-field for an algebraic equation; choice of topology on some ambient space which reasonably admits more than one topology; an ambient topos in which the construction is supposed to live), might have finite cardinality for one choice of flavour, but infinite cardinality for other choices?

(ii) does this have anything to do with whether we equip a given space, broadly and vaguely conceived, with a Hausdorff or a non-Hausdorff topology?

(iii) do either of these have any connection to the original subject, namely that certain mathematical constructions appear to have physical meaning yet be defined in terms of unphysical infinities?

The answer to (i) is in my view "yes, but so what?" and the answer to (ii) is in my view "I don't really think so". Moreover, I don't think (iii) is really dependent on (ii), and so my overall impression is that the "Hausdorff discussion" is a red herring.

Lastly, I am having difficulty making sense of the reasoning behind this sentence in the original question:

> Now suppose that one of the various branching spacetime interpretations of quantum mechanics (MWI, MMI, etc.) is correct (personal aside: I am agnostic on this issue). The topology of the multiverse would thus be non-Hausdorff and, given these interpretations of QM, there ought to be an infinite number of branches. Given that, an infinite physical realization becomes possible.

Comment: Ian gives a very clear statement of his underlying concerns in this blog post of his: http://quantummoxie.wordpress.com/2010/01/31/the-nature-of-mathematics/ .  If he posted it as a separate (soft, community wiki) question I think people would be happy to answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** this is a response to an earlier version of the question, and so is rather speculative. I am not sure that I can edit this to be much use in response to the newer version, so I'm leaving it as it stands for now, except to strikethrough a closing remark which was wide of the mark.

---

I think that the original questioner may have something like this in mind (though since I'm not a telepath, Jim, corrections/comments are welcome).

When we explain the definition of Hausdorff, we talk about separating points from other points using open neighbourhoods. Now if your intuition comes from metric spaces, these neighbourhoods are balls. So one might think that Hausdorffness is to do with separating things by balls, Furthermore, one might be thinking of some notion of minimal ball size -- this *isn't* what Hausdorffness is about, but bear with me! I'm trying to recreate a train of thought, not recapitulate the correct definitions -- and so get the idea that in "contexts which are Hausdorff" certain postulated objects -- the collection of all Widgets that satisfy the Sveshnikov-Pelikan equation - are forced to be finite because of "the need to separate constituent parts with balls". (See the original post's 4th para.)

Pursuing this train of thought, one might then wonder that if this postulated object is *not* finite, this is something to do with the failure of Hausdorffness. Again, I think this comes from a misapprehension about the Hausdorff separation condition; but at least this interpretation makes some sense of the original post's 1st para.

For the record: of course, things are more likely to be Hausdorff when you have more open sets, and of course a completely discrete space is Hausdorff for the trivial reason that every set is open. At the other extreme, a space with the indiscrete topology and more than two points has no chance of being Hausdorff. However, this has absolutely nothing to do with constraining the underlying set to be finite or infinite, contra the apparent guess of the original question. (If it helps: in the definition of Hausdorff, we don't constrain "the size of our open balls" before picking our two points; given any two points in, say, a metric space, we *then* have the freedom to choose a mesh size which will distinguish between them.) In particular, the sentence which starts "The topology of the multiverse would therefore be non-Hausdorff..." is in my view based on a misunderstanding, either of the word "Hausdorff" or the word "therefore"...

<strike>A comment for Ian, if I may: the reaction you got was because you started with a misuse of mathematical terminology, inserted into a question with words like "context" which are by nature philosophical/cultural rather than mathematical. It's that clash of tones which I think confused/irked some of the commenters.</strike>

Comment: Actually, I have thought of one context where a set, defined a certain way, will be "finite in the Hausdorff context but infinite in the non-Hausdorff one" -- however, I don't think it has any physical reality and will not help the original poster. The context is "closure of 0 " in a complete seminormed space -- just look at 21  given the quotient topology for an example where this closure is infinite; and look at your favourite Banach space (e.g. the ground field) for an example where it is finite.

Comment: @YC: The one mathematical thought that I got from the question was an example of a space (e.g. a pseudometric space or uniform space) which is infinite, but whose universal separated (T_0 = T_1 = T_2 for uniform spaces) quotient is finite, e.g. the indiscrete topology.  Does this have something to do with the question?  With your answer?  (I am very confused...)

Comment: @PLC: well, that's certainly related to my comment, but I'm not sure if it's connected to the question. I'm certainly not sure that these kinds of issue help with the questioner's underlying motive (which seems to be seeking some kind of framework to reconcile physical reality with multiverses)

Comment: Oops, I see that in my first comment some of the LaTeX went wrong. The example I meant to give was l^2(N) / l^1(N), given the quotient topology

Comment: @YC: Actually I had originally said "on" and not "in the context of" but changed it when the initial complaints came in.  Dinner is on the table but I will be back in a bit to clarify the original question.

Comment: @YC:  Ok, I made some more changes that hopefully get my point across a bit better (plus I added the definition for Hausdorff v. non-Hausdorff from which I am working).  As a note, I'm not really interested in the multiverse itself.  The question was simply motivated by an attempt to reconcile mathematics with the real world in the context of the Quine-Putnam argument since there are mathematical results that can't exist as physical objects in the universe.  The multiverse is simply the physical analogue of a non-Hausdorff topology.